# About the syntax of regular expression

Tags: regex, syntax, expression

I found a piece of code that accidentally outputs strange and inefficient regular expressions such as

```
a(a|a)b
```

which gets an `a|a` (two identical expressions connected by `|`)

Is such expression syntactically right? I can easily fix it, but I just want to know whether such expressions are valid or not, because this one seems bugs-free so far.

Comment: Just to be completely sure, the regex is `a(a|a)b` and not the rest of the text in the code block?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, this is syntactically equivalent to the regex /a(a)b/ - just slower.

Comment: er, actually it is not a piece of code, some module produce by others... Im not very familiar with the syntax, but as long as it works, Im happy, If Im gonna fix it, I will check and fix the output with some regular expressions...LOL

Comment: @Ghostblade Yes, there's no reason for it not to be valid. It just makes your regex slower for each `|a`

Answer (score 1):

What the regex `a(a|a)b` indicates is,

[image]

And  the regex `aab` indicates

[image]

And both will matches the input `aab`